# Determine all matrices that satisfy an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

"Determine, up to conjugacy, all 3×3 matrices $M$ over $Q$ that satisfy $M^3 = 2M^2$"

This is a question in the past qualifying exam of my university. I think it is insanely easy, that is why I want to verify my proof.

The minimal polynomial of $M$ must be $x, x^2, x-2,x(x-2)$ or $x^2(x-2)$.

In the first three cases, easy with $0, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $2I $.

In the 4th case, $M$ is diagonalizable, so $M $ is $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

Finally, $M= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

Did I forget anything? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Of course for a full answer you might want to shortly say why this the gives the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given six examples of $3\times3$-matrices that satisfy $M^3=2M^2$. You mention nothing about this being *all* such matrices, up to conjugacy. You should prove, or at least mention, *why* every matrix satisfying $M^3=2M^2$ is conjugate to one of these six matrices.